# How to use onsubmit function in another(second) php file?

Tags: javascript, php, html, google-maps

**First php file:**

```
 <form onsubmit="showAddress(this.address.value); return false;" method="post" >
    <h2>Enter Address</h2>
        <input type="number" class=" typeahead large_inputbox" name="address"  maxlength="6"/> 
      <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="submit" /> 
 </form>
```

**second php file:**

```
function showAddress(address) {
var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
 if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
  map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
  map.setMapTypeId(google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID);
  if (map.getZoom() < 16){map.setZoom(16);}else{}
  marker.setPosition(results[0].geometry.location);
  posset = 1;
  computepos(results[0].geometry.location);
 } else {
  alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
 } 

});
}
```

**How to use onsubmit function in another(second) php file?**

Comment: why do you want to use `onsubmit()` in second file

Comment: because showAddress parameter value to pick address on google map.. so i use showAddress function..

Answer (score 0):

You can include second php file inside first php file

Answer (score 0):

`showAddress` is actually a javascript function so it has to be defined in the current HTML page, or in one of the included javascript files.

You can include the php file that contains the function in your HTML file:

```
<script src="php_with_function.php" />
```

Or in php:

```
<script>
<?php require "php_with_function.php"; ?>
</script>
```

Comment: Please use <?php and not <?, because short tags are maybe disabled in the configuration